# Axios proxy when deploying on Heroku

Tags: express, heroku, deployment, axios, mern

When deploying a MERN application on Heroku, from the material available online I see that we set the "**proxy**" to **localhost:5000** (or which ever port our express server is running on).

When deployed, how does the proxy resolves to the actual domain? I am pretty confused with this concept.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you wonder how to send requests to your app deployed on heroku. If I understand it correctly here it is.

You set your port like this. Getting the port with SERVER_PORT key is important because heroku will provide a SERVER_PORT environment variable for you.

```
http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3206);
```

And you don't need to think about ip address. Heroku will handle that as well. After the deployment you will get a link somewhere in the panel. You can use that link to send requests.